# Problem with SQL Connection exception on creating object

Tags: c#, sql-server

I created a SQL Server database in Visual Studio 2013.

I have a problem when I am trying to create a new `SqlConnection` object. The same code worked yesterday, but now I have some problem. I also added the `SQLException` but I can't reach this code

```
try
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyKey"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    sqlConnection.Open();
}
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlException)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(sqlException.Message);
}

Application.Run(new LoginForm());
```

`SqlConnection` did not work. This is the exception. I don't know what it is wrong because it did work before

> System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233036
>   Message=The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'                 threw an exception.
>   Source=System.Data
>   TypeName=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String                 connectionString)
>
> InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
>   HResult=-2146233079
>   Message=Failed to read the configuration section for enclave providers. Make sure the section is correctly formatted in your application configuration file.
>
> Error Message: Configuration system failed to initialize
>   Source=System.Data
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..cctor()
>
> InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
>   HResult=-2146232062
>   Message=Configuration system failed to initialize
>   Source=System.Configuration
>   BareMessage=Configuration system failed to initialize
>   Line=0
>
> InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
>   HResult=-2146232062
>   Message=Root element is missing. 
>   Source=System.Configuration
>   BareMessage=Root element is missing.
>
> Line=0
>
> InnerException: System.Xml.XmlException
>   HResult=-2146232000
>   Message=Root element is missing.
>   Source=System.Xml

app.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="MercazApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyKey"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\Taekwon-Do\MercazApp\DB\LoginDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <userSettings>
    <MercazApp.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="username" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="password" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="name" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
    </MercazApp.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The error might be caused by error in `app.config`/`web.config`. Post your config

Comment: `Root element is missing. (C:\Users\alexs\AppData\Local\MercazApp\MercazApp.exe_Url_ka1yz14eyfxx0cttxywliv5ag3ke50uk\1.0.0.0\user.config)` seems relevant. Likely, that file changed to something bad. Inspect it.

Comment: Where I put this root element? I will add app.config

Comment: I can't believe you! I renamed that folder to old and after building it was created again and now it works!! I spent 4 hours with that. Where did you see the error and why it caused?

Answer (score 2):

> Root element is missing. (C:\Users\alexs\AppData\Local\MercazApp\MercazApp.exe_Url_ka1yz14eyfxx0cttxywliv5ag3ke50uk\1.0.0.0\user.config)

seems relevant. Likely, that file changed to something bad. Inspect it.

> I can't believe you! I renamed that folder to old and after building it was created again and now it works!! I spent 4 hours with that. Where did you see the error and why it caused?

I simply read the exception in full. Exceptions contain a lot of information. It is worth acquiring a habit to fully read, understand and interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the connection string directly into the code in place of the line that says:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyKey"].ConnectionString;
```

This will tell you whether it's a web.config issue. Since it started playing up suddenly, its quite likely that some config change in IIS triggered the web config to be updated.

also worth checking whther there are any other .config files in different folders (including app_data) if you find one with no content, just delete it.

Comment: static string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\Taekwon-Do\MercazApp\DB\LoginDb.mdf;Integrated Security = True";
        static SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);